# USB connection to move a Servo Motor

Tags: arduino

I want to know how to connect a phone to an arduino via usb and then have a servo motor move once the arduino recognizes that it is a phone. I'm very very new to arduino but I think it is an arduino uno.

We haven't tried anything yet because we don't know if out school has the proper hardware. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a pretty wide open question.  You'll get better results if you ask a more-specific questions that focus on the programming aspect of the problem, which might involve breaking it down into two or more questions.  For example, do you need help programming the phone to send data out the USB?  Or programming the Arduino to receive the data?  Or programming the Arduino to move the servos?  If you search around, you'll probably find lots of information on at least some of those.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Thank you so much for your help!  We are looking to program the arduino to receive data from the usb and to program it to sense that a phone is connected.

Comment: check any tutorial on how to move a servo.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way for the Arduino to just "know" what it's connected to. The USB connection is handled with the USB to TTL converter on the board and thats what the computer sees. The rest of the Arduino board is simply rxing or txing serial data if there is any and there wont be unless you send something. You would have to send some serial data from the phone using an app to identify the phone.
If you give more detail, then maybe we can figure out some other way to solve the problem.